# Can not create attributes in a Class

Tags: java

I have defined a Class named Cell, if i call the constructor i get an Overflow execption.
Why cant i call buildallneigbors() inside the constructor?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.lang.Exception;
    
        public final class Cell {
            private int row;
            private int column;
                public Cell neigborcell[];
                public List<Border> borderlist;
                private int hashwert;
   
            
            public Cell(int row, int column) {
                this.row = row;
                this.column = column;
                Cell neigborcell[] = new Cell[4];
               List<Border> borderlist = new ArrayList<Border>();
              buildallneigbors();
        
            }

     public void buildallneigbors(){
            this.neigborcell[0] = new Cell(row - 1, column);
            this.neigborcell[1] = new Cell(row, column + 1);
            this.neigborcell[2] = new Cell(row + 1, column);
            this.neigborcell[3] = new Cell(row, column - 1);
        }
```

Comment: You're basically creating an infinite loop.  Since the constructor calls the constructor for 4 new Cells, each of which calls the constructor for 4 new Cells, each of which...

Comment: So can you tell me, how cdo i aviod the loop, but still build all neigborcells ?

Comment: Presumably, the Cells are going to be instantiated into some kind of array, matrix or list, right?  Clearly, you can't load up the neighbour cells until they've been instantiated.  So modify `buildAllNeighbors()` to take your collection of cells, so `buildAllNeighbors(Collection allCells)`.  Then write a function to search through the collection to find a cell with [row-1, column] and so forth.

Comment: By the way, why are you mixing lists and arrays? Lists are way more flexible (and easier to use), so you don't really need arrays here, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to populate the `neighborCell[]` you need to have the other Cells already instantiated.  So by it's nature it needs to be a two-pass operation.  One to create the cells, and another to populate the neighbours:

```
public class CellBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Cell> cells = IntStream.range(0, 6)
                                    .mapToObj(row -> IntStream.range(0, 7).mapToObj(column -> new Cell(row, column)))
                                    .flatMap(cell -> cell)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        cells.forEach(cell -> cell.buildAllNeigbors(cells));
    }

    public static final class Cell {
        private int row;
        private int column;
        public Cell neighbourCell[] = new Cell[4];

        public Cell(int row, int column) {
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
        }

        public void buildAllNeigbors(Collection<Cell> allCells) {
            this.neighbourCell[0] = locateCell(allCells, row - 1, column);
            this.neighbourCell[1] = locateCell(allCells, row, column + 1);
            this.neighbourCell[2] = locateCell(allCells, row + 1, column);
            this.neighbourCell[3] = locateCell(allCells, row, column - 1);
        }

        private Cell locateCell(Collection<Cell> cells, int rowToFind, int columnToFind) {
            return cells.stream().filter(cell -> cell.row == rowToFind).filter(cell -> cell.column == columnToFind).findAny().orElse(null);
        }
    }
}
```